# How to Prevent access from a certain folder?

Tags: windows, delphi, directory

I want to lock a certain folder and unlock it using a password, any ideeas ?

PS I am a delphi coder!

Comment: this belongs on severfault, and it would help to know the o/s.

Comment: @glob re-read the question. This is a perfectly valid programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exist several approaches:

1. block access to the folder to any
   application until it's unlocked. The
   files remain unchanged.
2. encrypt all
   files in the folder and decrypt them
   on-the-fly.
3. move the files to
   encrypted storage and mount this
   storage as a virtual folder.

The first approach is flawed as it lets the user reboot the system in safe mode or just take the HDD to other computer and gain access to the folder.

Second approach is possible using file system filter driver. You can write your own or you can use our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) product (which includes Encrypt sample for this particular purpose).

Third approach is also possible using our products. You can mount a virtual storage as a disk or as a folder on NTFS disk using [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfls/) (see VMounter sample).

There exists also Pismo File Mount product on the market and it would work for you out of the box if it had Delphi API. That product mounts a container as a folder on the disk using FS Filter driver. Personally I am not fond of this approach, though -- FS filter drivers are trickier than file system drivers and more prone to conflicts with third-party filters.